# Parse XML file and insert results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

I am trying to import a XML file into a MySQL database and I am having some issues along the way. This is the code that I have so far:

```
function convertXML($node){
    foreach($node->Body->Cube as $child)
        {
            echo $child['date'] .",";
                foreach($child->Rate as $child1)
                {
                    echo $response=$child1 . ",";
                }
            echo "<br>";
                   //mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ('date', 'AED', 'AUD', 'BGN', 'BRL') VALUES $response");
        }
}
$row = convertXML($xml);
```

And this is a sample of my XML file:

```
<DataSet>
    <Header>
      <PublishingDate>2012-12-04</PublishingDate>
      <MessageType>DR</MessageType>
    </Header>
    <Body>
      <Subject>Reference</Subject>
      <OrigCurrency>RO</OrigCurrency>
       <Cube date="2012-12-03">
          <Rate currency="AED">0.9439</Rate>
          <Rate currency="AUD">3.6275</Rate>
          .....
          <Rate currency="BGN">2.3170</Rate>
       </Cube>
       <Cube date="2012-12-04">
          <Rate currency="AED">0.93129</Rate>
          <Rate currency="AUD">3.3576</Rate>
           ....
          <Rate currency="BGN">2.245/Rate>
       </Cube>
    </Body>
</DataSet>
```

I can get the results that I am interested (date and the numeric value from the RAte currency child) and print them on the screen but I am having a hard time introducing them into the database. Any help will be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: At one point I would like to automate this somehow so I need to have script to run at predefined intervals ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE`???

```
mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'address.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE person
    ->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<person>';
```

more information here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html